# Adding a fractions and classes - Woot

Tags: c++, class, fractions

Hey guys to start off I will say that I have looked into a lot of similar programs before posting this question and still need some help. My problem lies in the addition fraction class function where I need to add one fraction to another. I have one class and am currently working with to instances of that class (fractionObject and fractionObject2). I am storing my fractions separately, one in fractionObject and one in fractionObject2. How can I add these in my fraction class function 'Add'?

Any tips will be much appreciated! Thanks for your time!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

// Regular prototypes
int stringToNumber(const string &Text);
int GCD(int, int);
int LCM(int, int);

class fraction{

public: // Access Specifier
    int numerator;
    int  denominator; // Can never be 0



    // Function Prototypes
    fraction();
    void setNumDen();
    void reduce();
    void add();


};

// Member functions definitions
fraction::fraction()
{
    numerator = 0;
    denominator = 0;
}

void fraction::setNumDen()
{
    string numString;
    string denString;
    do{
        cout << "Enter a numerator and denominator of fraction 1 separated by whitespace: ";
        getline(cin, numString, ' ');
        getline(cin, denString);
        if (denString == "0")
            cout << endl << "Please enter a number that isn't zero." << endl;
    } while (denString == "0"); // Making sure denominator is not zero

    numerator = stringToNumber(numString);
    denominator = stringToNumber(denString);

}

void fraction::reduce()
{
    int leastCommonMultiple = 0;

    leastCommonMultiple = LCM(numerator, denominator);

    numerator /= leastCommonMultiple;
    denominator /= leastCommonMultiple;
}

void fraction::add()
{
    int leastComDen;

}

int main()
{

    fraction fractionObject, fractionObject2;

    fractionObject.setNumDen();
    fractionObject2.setNumDen();
    // Reducing and displaying the reduced fractions
    fractionObject.reduce();
    fractionObject2.reduce();
    cout << "Reduced Fraction 1 = " << fractionObject.numerator << "/" << fractionObject.denominator << "\t" << "Reduced Fraction 2 = " << fractionObject2.numerator << "/" << fractionObject2.denominator << endl;
    // Adding and displaying the fractions



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

// Function to convert string to number
int stringToNumber(const string &Text)//Text not by const reference so that the function can be used with a 
{                               //character array as argument
    stringstream ss(Text);
    int result;
    return ss >> result ? result : 0;
}

// result=GCD(a,b)
int LCM(int a, int b) {
    int temp = 0;

    while (b != 0) {
        temp = b;
        b = a%b;
        a = temp;
    }
    return a;
}

// result=LCM(a,b);
int GCD(int a, int b) {
    int result = 0;

    result = a * (b / LCM(a, b));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I recommend starting with a change to the add prototype: `void add(const fraction & toAdd);` Pass in the fraction to be added to `this` fraction.

Comment: Thanks for your input I did this and am still working to figure it out!

Comment: Note that since you have a reduce method you don't need to find the least common denominator first (as it appears you plan to do). Just find **a** common multiple (e.g. the product of the two denominators) the call reduce when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

No complete answer here, but add should have two `const fraction&` arguments and return a temporary `fraction` object.  You might rename it `operator+`.  Many libraries add a `+=` operator that doesn't require making a temporary object.  C++11 allows you to reduce the overhead of these temporary objects with a move constructor.

As for the implementation, here’s a hint: 1/6 + 1/9 = (9+6)/54 = 5/18. I notice you already have a reduce function.

Comment: Mostly agree. If `add` was going to take two fractions and return a new fraction it should be either a static method or a free function. `reduce` alters the object and `add` should behave the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I'm getting closer to figuring this out!